# Human Generator Ultimate Rigify not working

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

I've just updated from Human Gen 3 to the new Ultimate version, but when I click "Generate Rigify Rig" in the add-on, it only generates the ground arrows. There seems to be some problem with the meta-rig that is automatically generated by Human Gen and it doesn't translate properly to Rigify.

Has anyone else dealt with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just figured it out. You have to select the meta-rig, click the *Data* tab and click *Upgrade Armature*, then you can go back to the Human Gen add-on and click *Generate Rigify Rig*.